# Call a function with the address extracted from vector of lists, lists are address of functions

Tags: c++, list, function, vector, function-pointers

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>


typedef std::list<void *> funcList;

typedef struct {
  funcList* functionsList;
  char* listName;
}ListAccess_t;

namespace FuncListManager{
  //namespace {
    std::vector<funcList> funcBuffer;
    std::mutex funcMutex;
 // }

  static size_t findEmptyList() {
    for (size_t index = 0; index < funcBuffer.size(); index++) {
      if (funcBuffer[index].empty()) {
        return index;
      }
    }
    return funcBuffer.size();
  }

  size_t getAvalableListIndex() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(funcMutex);
    if (funcBuffer.size() != findEmptyList()) {
      return findEmptyList();
    }
    else {
      return -1;
    }
  }

  void addFunction(size_t listIndex, void* func) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(funcMutex);
    funcBuffer[listIndex].push_back(func);
  }

  void removeFunction(size_t listIndex, void* func) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(funcMutex);
    if (listIndex < funcBuffer.size()) {
      auto& myFuncList = funcBuffer[listIndex];

      auto it = std::find(myFuncList .begin(), myFuncList .end(), func);

      if (it != myFuncList .end()) {
        myFuncList .erase(it);
      }
    }
  }

  void createFunctionList(size_t capacity) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(funcMutex);
    funcBuffer.resize(capacity);
  }

  funcList* getFunctionListPointer(size_t listIndex) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(funcMutex);
    if (listIndex < funcBuffer.size()) {
      return &funcBuffer[listIndex];
    }
    return nullptr;
  }
}

void (*addNumber_t)(int a, int b);

void addnumber(int a, int b) {
  int c = a + b;
}


int main() {
  
  FuncListManager::createFunctionList(5);
  size_t index = FuncListManager::getAvalableListIndex();

  addNumber_t = &addnumber;
  FuncListManager::addObserver(index, (void*)&addnumber);
  ListAccess_t *listAccess = new ListAccess_t();

  listAccess->functionsList= FuncListManager::getObserverListPointer(index);
  listAccess->listName = "list access";

  ObserverList *list = listAccess->functionsList;

  for (auto& func: *list) {
    ((addNumber_t)func)(1,2); //how to call add function here
    int i = 0;
  }

  FuncListManager::removeFunction(index, (void*)&addnumber);

  return 0;
}
```

I have to create vector of lists and each list is the collection of address of functions (which are referenced with function pointers).
How it is possible to call the functions which are added to the vector of lists?

I don't want to use the classes, it's a library under a namespace.

I tried to call the extracted function from the list, but it throws compilation error.

Comment: `addNumber_t` is a variable, not a type. `typedef void (*addNumber_t)(int, int);` would declare it as a type alias.

Comment: Is it technically (as per the specification) possible to use a `void*` pointer to point to functions? IIRC it's not, pointers to functions are a different thing from general pointers to data or objects.

Comment: `typedef std::list<void *> funcList;`? How would you call a function if you lose its type? +@Someprogrammerdude remark.

Comment: And why do you use `typedef` for structures? A `struct` in C++ is just like a `class`, and the structure (or class) tag name is also a type name. And generally, avoid the confusing `typedef` keyword for creating type-aliases, in favor of `using`. As in `using funcList = std::list<void*>;` (but please keep my previous comment in mind)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think so. If I recall, ordinary function pointers _do_ fit in a pointer, whereas pointer-to-member-function is special and does not necessarily fit (although in practice it tends to).

Comment: @paddy - Posix requires `void*` to be wide enough to hold a function pointer, but the language only requires it to hold the [address of "objects"](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.compound#6), and a function is not an object.